# Is there a way to set an output of a function as a pointer to an array of 3 elements?

Tags: c++

If a have something like
`double A[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`
How do I define the function if I want the command `return A` to work?

Comment: You could make it `static` - but please show the context. Perhaps there are better ways.

Comment: Most likely you should be using some like `std::array` instead

Comment: The typical way to do this is to put that array inside a named class type that represents what the array is.  You can then pass that around however you want.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do I represent this with std::array or std::vector? I'm a beginner I'm not familiar with these commands.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: A classical example would be to pass a pointer to the destination array and modify the destination array.

Answer (score 1):

In classical C++ (and C), you don't want to pass copies of large data structures; this is one of the reasons for pointer.

```
void My_Function(double * A)
{
    double  My_Array[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    double * p_array = &My_Array[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(My_Array); ++i)
    {
        A[i] = p_array[i];
    }
}
```

A *safer* solution would be to pass the destination *vector* by reference:

```
void Another_Function(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& destination)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> my_vector=
    {
       {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}
    }
    destination = my_vector;
}
```

The above code fragments are accessing the Caller's array rather than having the compiler return an array (by value) then assigning that value to the Caller's variable.  Accessing the Caller's array uses less memory and is often more efficient.

Comment: [Error] '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list[Error] in C++98 'my_vector' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'            I just copy pasted but it returns this error... is it my problem?

Comment: The issue was fixed in a more recent version of C++.  You can use spaces between `>` or `<`.

Comment: `[Error] in C++98 'my_vector' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'` sorry to disturb, but what about this part?

Comment: I recommend you research the [`std::vector` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)